# Is Normality stable under scalar extension?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question is as follows.

Let $X$: a normal variety over field $K$ and $L/K$ : Galois extension of $K$.
My Claim is $X_L = X \times \text{Spec}\,L$ (fibre product) is also normal variety.

I don't know whether this claim is true or false. If it is true, how can we prove this??

Comment: Can you prove it for affine varieties? Can you at least make explicit what the claim is in that case?

Comment: My Claim is $X_L=X \times_{K} \text{Spec}\,L$ is also normal variety. But i don't know how to prove this

Comment: I meant (and wrote) that it is probably a good idea that you write down what this means, in concrete terms, in the case where $X$ is an affine variety.

Comment: It depends, I guess, on what you mean by variety. Anyway I think you just need separability. My guess is that one can find a long trail of lemmas in the Stacks project that sees this out but I'll try to write something direct if I have time tomorrow.

Comment: In this problem, variety means that geometrically integral, finite type over K
, separated scheme. We may assume $X=\text{Spec}\,A$ where $A$ is an integral domain and $K$-algebra. And we have $A$ is an integrally closed domain. Then, we have to show that $A⊗_{K}L$ is also integrally closed domain. Thank you!